# Filtering object keys in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing an assessment right now and I am allowed to use what ever resources I want, just a preface. The prompt I was given was to use .filter to filter out all objects with out a specific key, here is the prompt...

Write a function called cookieLoversOnly that takes 
in an array and filters out every object that
does NOT have the key favoriteCookie.
cookieLoversOnly should return the filtered array.

This is what I have so far...

```js
function cookieLoversOnly(arr){
return arr.filter(e => arr[e]===favoriteCookie)
}
```

Comment: So, `e` is your object in the filter, how about using `hasOwnProperty`? `return arr.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty("favoriteCookie"))`

Comment: no need to use arr[e], e is the value inside arr.

Comment: please add some data to highlight the problem.

Comment: `arr.filter(e => !e.favouriteCookie)` - il do the homework for you ;)

Comment: Aren't you looking for items that do not have the key favoriteCookie?

Comment: You don't need to propagate to the delegation on a proto-chain for 'favoriteCookie'?

Comment: e.favouriteCookie will not work if the object does have the key favouriteCookie and its value is boolean. use hasOwnProperty to check for keys

Answer (score -2):

Here are some examples of `arr.filter(e => !e.favouriteCookie)`

```js
let people = [
  {
    name: 'Mr Fooman',
    job: 'Dog walker',
    favouriteAnimal: 'Dog'
  },
  {
    job: 'Barman',
    favouriteFood: 'Cookies',
    favouriteCookie: 'Double Choc Chip',
    favouriteAnimal: 'Fox'
  },
  {
    name: 'Miss Baz',
    favouriteFood: 'Caesar Salad',
    favouriteCookie: 'Raisin',
    favouriteAnimal: 'Elephant'
  }
];
let demons = [
  {
    name: "demon 1",
    favouriteCookie: false
  },
  {
    name: "demon 2",
    favouriteCookie: true
  },
  {
    name: "demon 3",
    favouriteCookie: undefined
  },
  {
    name: "demon 4",
    favouriteCookie: null
  }
];

function cookieLoversOnly(arr){
  return arr.filter(e => e.favouriteCookie)
}

console.log("people:", cookieLoversOnly(people));

console.log("demons:", cookieLoversOnly(demons));
```

and therefore this answer is wrong, if you take the question literally.